# Problem with trigger for avoiding insert (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to make a trigger to avoid inserting data in the table for this reason:
If a patient is dead he can't make a visit.
I made a function that return a 1 if the patient is dead and I call it on the trigger. That's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_d (pd INTEGER)
RETURN INTEGER
IS
d Patient.d_date%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT P.d_Date INTO d
FROM Patient P
WHERE P.idP=pd;
IF d <> NULL THEN
    RETURN 1;
ELSE
    RETURN 0;   
END IF;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bad_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON Visit
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
idd INTEGER;
dp  Visit.id_PV%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT V.id_PV INTO dp
FROM Visit V
WHERE id_PV=:NEW.id_PV;

idd := check_d(dp);
IF idd = 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20014,'Error. Patient Deceased.');
END IF;
END;
/
```

The function should be ok, the problem is in thet trigger.
Visit.id_PV is a Foreign Key to Patient.idP(PRIMARY KEY) anyway. How should I modify the code? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you `SELECT V.id_PV INTO dp` in the trigger since you already have the `:NEW.id_PV` value ?

Comment: I don't undertand well the steps, but I think the select in the trigger is not gonna work, the :NEW.id_PV doesn't exist yet to compare as you are doing an insert. I would try as @SuperPoney says, just take the value from there.

Comment: In your data model, do you delete the row for a patient when that patient dies? It might be better to update the patient status. But how is the foreign key defined anyway, if `patient` is parent of `visit`?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not correct

```
d <> NULL
```

Will always return UNKNOWN, instead you have to check for nulls like:

```
d is not null
```

Once you've fixed that, you still have to work around the mutating table error you'd receive when you try an insert statement (did you not receive this when you tried it?). You are referencing the same table you are inserting into within your trigger. You can't do that. Instead you should reference the column you want using :new.id_PV .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is located here :

`IF d <> NULL THEN`

Change it to :

`IF d IS NOT NULL THEN`

Answer (score 0):

In the current case, you'll get `no_data_found` exception because of the query within the trigger. Moreover, you do not need to return the value for `id_PV` column that you already have as `:NEW.id_PV`, and such attempt mostly end with `mutating trigger` error. So , rearrange your trigger as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bad_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON Visit
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF check_d(:NEW.id_PV) = 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20014, 'Error. Patient Deceased.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

while getting rid of redundant local variables.

The function might also be made brief such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_d (pd Visit.id_PV%type) RETURN INT IS
 val INT;
BEGIN
 SELECT NVL(SUM(NVL2(P.d_Date,1,0)),0) 
   INTO val
   FROM Patient P
  WHERE P.idP=pd;
  
 RETURN val; 
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0f66a6818eabd87d11be7fd50f2b79f)</kbd>